# How merge too big .txt files in only one?

Tags: shell, cat, fat32

I have 7 files (approximately 4.7 GB each one) and I want to merge them into a single file.

I tried:

```
$ cat file1 file2 file3 ... > NewFile.txt
```

and I got this:

```
cat: stdout: File too large
```

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) what to do when you have resolved your issue with the help of the answer(s)

Answer (score 3):

"File too large" is a common error when trying to work with files greater than 4GB on a Fat32 filesystem.

If you're trying to combine the files on a Fat32 filesystem, you're going to have to need to combine them on a different drive formatted to exFat or NTFS (or for linux ex2/3/4).

Comment: thanks a lot, I copied the files to NTFS drive and really works!!